# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index error

Tags: java, excel, oracle

Require help..

I have requirement to read excel data and inserts data to oracle db table. When I run the program, I am getting error invalid column index. Searched articles and could not find solution.

Code snippet:

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Please post some relevant code.

Comment: Post the code that you are trying to execute so that can we can look in to it and understand what the problem is so that we can help you.!!

Answer (score 1):

Invalid column index exception is occurred due to calling or trying to read data from column which is not present.... In simple words ,the column number is wrong in curser.getint() lines

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are pulling values from your result set using a numeric index and the index you are attempting to access does not exist. Run the query in Oracle and confirm that you are getting the results you expect.

You could also add a try-with-resources block to earn some extra points, and output the offending column/index in the catch just for debugging purposes..

Answer (score 0):

Replying without any code snippet:

## Scenario n.1 (ResultSet)

In Java (SQL) you could get a `Invalid column index error` when try to get a variable in a `ResultSet`

**Example**:

```
ResultSet rs = ...;
try {
    if (rs != null) {
        rs.next();
        return rs.getInt(1);
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle the exception
}
```

In this case you have a result you're trying to get a column.
To get the first column (remember, **arrays start from 0**) you'll need to write `rs.getX(0)` (change `X` to your value type)

Always check if the **ResultSet** is **null** (using `if (rs != null)`)

## Scenario n.2 (PreparedStatement)

In Java (SQL) you could get a `Invalid column index error` when you assign a variable in a `PreparedStatement`

Example:

```
try {
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE users SET name = ? WHERE id = ?");
    ps.setInt(1, "Sam");
    ps.setString(2, "24");
    ps.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle the exception
}
```

In this case you have a query and some parameter to **substitute** (`?` char), you can assign a value using the index (**that starts from 1 instead of 0**)

The first `?` has index 1, the second has index 2 and so on...
If your query doesn't have a `?` to substitute then you will get this `Exception` error